# updating state of a python class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to simulate a 3 x 3 board in python 3.6+ in which the 0 "tile" can move up, down, left or right. I am implementing the state as a list.

```
class Tiles(object):

    def __init__(self, state, n):

        self.n = n
        self.state = state

        self.blank_index = self.state.index(0)

    def display(self):
        """ Tile state as a n*n board """
        for i in range(self.n):
            print(self.state[3 * i: 3 * (i + 1)])

    def move_up(self):
        blank = self.blank_index
        print("Blank is at position {}.".format(blank))
        if blank <= 2:
            return None
        else:
            up = self.state
            up[blank], up[blank - 3] = up[blank - 3], up[blank]
            Tiles.display(self)
            return Tiles(up, self.n)

    def move_down(self):
        blank = self.blank_index
        print("Blank is at position {}.".format(blank))
        if blank > 5:
            return None
        else:
            down = self.state
            down[blank], down[blank + 3] = down[blank + 3], down[blank]
            Tiles.display(self)
            return Tiles(down, self.n)

    def move_left(self):
        blank = self.blank_index
        print("Blank is at position {}.".format(blank))
        if blank == 0 or blank == 3 or blank == 6:
            return None
        else:
            left = self.state
            left[blank], left[blank - 1] = left[blank - 1], left[blank]
            Tiles.display(self)
            return Tiles(left, self.n)

    def move_right(self):
        blank = self.blank_index
        print("Blank is at position {}.".format(blank))
        if blank == 2 or blank == 5 or blank == 8:
            return None
        else:
            right = self.state
            right[blank], right[blank + 1] = right[blank + 1], right[blank]
            Tiles.display(self)
            return Tiles(right, self.n)

def move_seq(self):
    self.display()
    self.move_up()
    self.move_left()
    self.move_right()


def main():
    initial = [4,3,2,1,0,8,7,6,5]
    new_tiles = Tiles(initial, 9)
    move_seq(new_tiles)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But my output is unexpected...

```
[4, 3, 2]
[1, 0, 8]
[7, 6, 5]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
Blank is at position 4.
[4, 0, 2]
[1, 3, 8]
[7, 6, 5]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
Blank is at position 4.
[4, 0, 2]
[3, 1, 8]
[7, 6, 5]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
Blank is at position 4.
[4, 0, 2]
[3, 8, 1]
[7, 6, 5]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

I am having trouble comprehending why (1) the `self.move_up()` call in function `move_seq(self)` displays the desired output but the subsequent method calls do not, (2) why the updated state isn't saved i.e. `Blank is at position 4` and (3) why there are extra empty list objects printing in `display`.

Thank you in advance for aiding me in my understanding!

Comment: I've updated my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Tiles(object):
    def __init__(self, state, n):

        self.n = n
        self.state = state

        self.blank_index = self.state.index(0)

    def display(self):
        """ Tile state as a n*n board """
        for i in range(self.n//3):
            print(self.state[3 * i : 3 * (i + 1)])

    def move_up(self):
        blank = self.blank_index
        print("Blank is at position {}.".format(blank))
        if blank <= 2:
            return None
        else:
            up = self.state
            up[blank], up[blank - 3] = up[blank - 3], up[blank]
            self.blank_index = self.state.index(0)
            self.display()

    def move_down(self):
        blank = self.blank_index
        print("Blank is at position {}.".format(blank))
        if blank > 5:
            return None
        else:
            down = self.state
            down[blank], down[blank + 3] = down[blank + 3], down[blank]
            self.blank_index = self.state.index(0)
            self.display()

    def move_left(self):
        blank = self.blank_index
        print("Blank is at position {}.".format(blank))
        if blank == 0 or blank == 3 or blank == 6:
            return None
        else:
            left = self.state
            left[blank], left[blank - 1] = left[blank - 1], left[blank]
            self.blank_index = self.state.index(0)
            self.display()

    def move_right(self):
        blank = self.blank_index
        print("Blank is at position {}.".format(blank))
        if blank == 2 or blank == 5 or blank == 8:
            return None
        else:
            right = self.state
            right[blank], right[blank + 1] = right[blank + 1], right[blank]
            self.blank_index = self.state.index(0)
            self.display()


def move_seq(obj):
    obj.display()
    obj.move_up()
    obj.move_left()
    obj.move_right()


def main():
    initial = [4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 8, 7, 6, 5]
    new_tiles = Tiles(initial, 9)
    move_seq(new_tiles)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**EXPLANATION:**

Firstly, you are never updating the blank_index instance attribute of the initial object.  For example, in this code:

```
    def move_up(self):
        blank = self.blank_index
        print("Blank is at position {}.".format(blank))
        if blank <= 2:
            return None
        else:
            up = self.state
            up[blank], up[blank - 3] = up[blank - 3], up[blank]
            self.display()
            return Tiles(up, self.n)
```

blank will always be the initial "4", for move_up, move_left, move_right, and move_down.  You should instead update this attribute after modifying the `state` attribute as such:

```
    def move_up(self):
        blank = self.blank_index
        print("Blank is at position {}.".format(blank))
        if blank <= 2:
            return None
        else:
            up = self.state
            up[blank], up[blank - 3] = up[blank - 3], up[blank]
            self.blank_index = self.state.index(0)
            self.display()
```

You are then creating new `Tiles` instances and returning them... and yet, you are never using these new objects because you are never assigning these returned objects to new variables, and all of your calls in

```
# Note: You should not use the variable "self" outside of a class... in this instance it would make more sense to use something like "obj" (short for object).
def move_seq(obj):
    obj.display()
    obj.move_up()
    obj.move_left()
    obj.move_right()
```

are calling methods of the INITIAL object!

Also, you are printing out a bunch of blank cells since you're iterating through the full size of the board, when really you want to be iterating across the number of rows you intend to print, in this case 3.

Comment: `Tiles.display(self)` doesn't create a new instance, it calls the method on the class and passes `self` as first parameter, which is equivalent to `self.display()`.

Comment: There are a multitude of issues I have addressed other than that.  `self.display()` is preferable.

Comment: This is extremely helpful! If I wanted to return the new state of the tile board after `move_up(self)` would I just `return Tiles(up, self.n)`

Comment: no need to return it because the initial object's state attribute has already been modified.  You can test this.  After creating the variable `up`, you will see that by modifying `up`, `self.state` is also modified.  Now if you wanted to create a new object with this newly modified state, yes you could return it, but you would want to assign it to something.  For example: `obj2 = obj.move_up()`.  Note, however, that both your new object and the initial object will be the same.

Comment: To print this new state, you could simply `print(obj.state)` or call `obj.display()` (both from *outside* the class.  From within a class method, replace `obj` with `self`.)